# xtext: expression/factor/term grammar

Tags: grammar, xtext

This has got to be one of those well-known examples that's somewhere on the internet, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to learn XText and I figured a calculator expression parser would be a good start. But I'm getting syntax errors in my grammar:

```
Expression:
    Term (('+'|'-') Term)*;

Term:
    Factor (('*'|'/') Factor)*;

Factor:
    number=Number | variable=ID | ('(' expression=Expression ')');
```

I get this error in the Expression and Term lines:

```
Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot change type twice within a rule
 - An unassigned rule call is not allowed, when the 'current'
   was already created.
```

What gives? How can I fix this? And when do I have `instanceName=Rule` vs. `Rule` entries in a grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded xtext integrated with eclipse and it comes with a calculator example which does approximately what you wish called arithmetics. From what I can gather you will need to assign an associativity to your tokens. This grammar runs fine for me:

```
Expression:
    Term (({Plus.left=current}'+'|{Minus.left=current}'-') right=Term)*;

Term:
    Factor (({Multiply.left=current} '*'| {Division.left=current}'/') right=Factor)*;

Factor:
    number=NUMBER | variable=ID | ('(' expression=Expression ')');
```

The example grammar they have for arithmetics can be viewed [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tmf/org.eclipse.xtext.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui.examples/contents/org.eclipse.xtext.example.arithmetics/src/org/eclipse/xtext/example/arithmetics/Arithmetics.xtext). It includes a bit more than your, like function calls, but the basics are the same.

Comment: that's very helpful! Can you point me towards a reference that describes what this '{Plus.left=current}' syntax means?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I never really tried xtext out before. But it looks to me that it generates an interface called `Plus` which builds up the parse tree. The .left associates the current token to the left part of the Apparently it's assigned actions: http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_0_0/020-grammar-language.php#syntax