# Xtext grammar left recursion - left factoring

Tags: antlr, xtext

I use Xtext in order to build a language that will support array expressions. At this time I have written rules for supporting mathematical expressions and now I'm trying to write a rule to support matrix multiplication (inner product).
The rules for math expressions follow the pattern suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444860/xtext-expression-factor-term-grammar). Among the rules there is the following Compare rule:

```
Compare returns Expression:
   Shift (({Gt.left=current} '>'| {Lt.left=current} '<') right=Shift)*
```

Below this rule there are other Rules such as Shift that contain operators of different precedence. All these rules lead to Atomic rule where I declare the valid operands of an Expression, among which I want to support inner product:

```
Atomic returns Expression:
   {NumberLiteral} value=NUMBER|
   {SymbolRef} symbol=[Symbol]|
   ...
   {InnerPr}'<'vect=Expr ',' vect2=Expr '>';
```

Now this causes left recursion. If I write the expression

```
<x,y>-5>
```

when the parser will reach the first "greater than" symbol will not be able to distinguish if it is a part of Compare rule or the closing tag of the inner product rule.
I hope I made myself clear. Although I understand the problem, I cannot solve it. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a syntactic predicate, e.g. something like this should do the trick:

```
{InnerPr} '<' vect=Expr ',' vect2=Expr =>'>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I still get "Decision can match input such as "'>' '<' RULE_ID" using multiple alternatives" and "Decision can match input such as "'>' '-' RULE_ID"" errors. It also says "Semantic predicates were present but were hidden by actions.". I will search what this means and will try your suggestion again.